# Two figures compared expressed as a percentage

Tags: percentage

I'm comparing the median sales value of two different categories here but the question is quite specific

What is 18,000 v 9,500 expressed as a percentage.

The target is an overall increase of 5% BY 2022 (2020 Figures provided).

It's the V bit that is concerning me. I thought it would be 89.5% so target more than achieved in year one.

Comment: When you are comparing things a very different scales you can use the geometric mean. A 10% change in something small causes the same motion as a 10% change in something big.

Comment: Thank you but that doesn't actually answer my question "What is 18,000 v 9,500 expressed as a percentage." The two figures provide are already the median sales value for two categories,

Comment: Versus often is word equivalent to a division sign. The ratio of 18000 to 9500 is a little less than 200%. The relative difference requires one to subtract then divide. (18000-9500)/9500. The result was going to be a bit less than 100%. One of the reasons for my comment is that often the math is the answer to the question different than the one you think you’re answering. This is especially true when businesses involved. It looks like you’re trying to compare two sets of things, and there are a lot of ways to do that, and some of them can be very easy and very misleading at the same time.